# Hex characters in a string

Tags: ruby, string, hex

How can I get a hexadecimal value inside a string so that its real character will appear?

Comment: You want to convert it to ASCII??

Comment: so do you want to know the format or remove UTF-8 characters?

Comment: I just want to know how I can place a hex value inside a string, like "0x3AA3", etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think something like this is what you want:

```
#encoding: ASCII-8BIT
str = "\xC2\xA92011 AACR"
p str, str.encoding
#=> "\xC2\xA92011 AACR"
#=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>

str.force_encoding('UTF-8')
p str, str.encoding
#=> "©2011 AACR"
#=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Comment: when I run this, I get: "\xC2\xA92011 AACR"
#<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
"\u00A92011 AACR"
#<Encoding:UTF-8>

Comment: I found that you need a double-quoted string to do this, single-quotes don't allow these escapes.